# Python Directory Display in Finder, Explorer, Dolphin, etc... (Cross-Platform)

Tags: python, cross-platform, directory

I would like to find some way of Viewing a Directory in the default file system viewer (Windows Explorer, Finder, Dolphin, etc...) that will work on all major platforms.
I do not have the detailed knowledge of Linux, nor of OSX in order to write this. Is there some script out there that will do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OSX:

```
os.system('open "%s"' % foldername)
```

Windows:

```
os.startfile(foldername)
```

Unix:

```
os.system('xdg-open "%s"' % foldername)
```

Combined:

```
import os

systems = {
    'nt': os.startfile,
    'posix': lambda foldername: os.system('xdg-open "%s"' % foldername)
    'os2': lambda foldername: os.system('open "%s"' % foldername)
     }

systems.get(os.name, os.startfile)(foldername)
```

Comment: Is the Unix compatible with Linux (dumb question, I know), and is it compatible with all distros?

Comment: Linux is a Unix-like system. And yes, it is compatible with all distros if they have xdg-open installed by default (all modern distros).

xdg-open is the most compatible way to open folders as there's no generic way to do this as you would need a different approach for every desktop manager.